# Contar la cantidad de caracteres de las propiedades de un Array en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, array, function, foreach

estoy presentando una dificultad en laravel. Necesito recorrer un array y poder contar de cada una de las propiedades y poder calcular cuantos caracteres tiene. Porque de estos valores obtenidos necesito decirle que solo acepte aquellos que tienen 21 caracteres, ni menos ni más. Es para una función store. No sé si es mejor una función de array o un foreach o for para poder resolver este problema.

public function UploadCodesFarmersStore(Request $request){

```
    $fields = [
        'category'=>'required',
        'tokens'=>'required',
        'account_info'=>'required',
        'type_payment'=>'required',
    ];

    $msj = [
        'category.required' => 'La categoría es requerida',
        'tokens.required' => 'El código es requerido',
        'account_info.required' => 'La información de cuenta para el pago es requerido',
        'type_payment.required' => 'El tipo de pago es requerido',
    ];

    $this->validate($request, $fields, $msj);

    $category = Category::where('to_sell', true)
        ->where('key_name', $request->category)
        ->first();

    if($category == null){
        toastr()->error('Ocurrio un error, esta categoria no esta permitida', '', ['timeOut' => 3000]);

        return redirect()->route('upload.codes.farmers.create');
    }

    $str_token = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\n\r", "\r", "\n", " ", ","), "|", $request->tokens);

    
    $array_token = explode('|', $str_token);


    if(count($array_token) == 0){
        toastr()->error('No existe el código', '', ['timeOut' => 3000]);
        return redirect()->route('upload.codes.farmers.create');
    }

   


    $codesValidates = DB::table('codes')->whereIn('code', $array_token)->get();

    $array_data = array_unique($array_token);
    $common_data = array_diff_assoc($array_token, $array_data); 
    $repeats = array_unique($common_data); 



    
    if(!empty($repeats) && sizeof($codesValidates) != 0){
        Session::flash('codes_validate_repit', $repeats);
        Session::flash('codes_validate_db', $codesValidates);
        return redirect()->route('upload.codes.farmers.create');
    }
    else if(!empty($repeats)){
        Session::flash('codes_validate_repit', $repeats);
        return redirect()->route('upload.codes.farmers.create');
    }   
    else if(sizeof($codesValidates) != 0){
        Session::flash('codes_validate_db', $codesValidates);
        return redirect()->route('upload.codes.farmers.create');
    }


$count = 0;

    do {
        $operation_code = mt_rand(100000000, 999999999);
        $validator = \Validator::make(
            ['operation_code' => $operation_code],
            ['operation_code' => 'unique:codes,operation_code']
        );
    } while ($validator->fails());

    foreach ($array_token as $key => $code) {
        
        $array = array(
            'code' => $code,
            'uid_discord' => Auth::user()->uid_discord,
            'price' => $request->type_payment == 'USD' ? $category->price_token_farmer : $category->price_token_farmer_bs,
            'category' => $request->category,
            'operation_code' => $operation_code,
        );

        $validator = Validator::make($array, [
            'uid_discord'   => 'required',
            'code'   => 'required|unique:codes',
            'price' => 'required',
            'category' => 'required'
        ]);

            if (!$validator->fails()) {;
                $model = Code::create($array);
                $count = $count + 1;
           }

    }


}
```

Esté es la función del controlador para guardar, necesito que antes de guardar me verifique si cada código tiene 21 caracteres. El problema que presento es que los códigos vienen dentro de un array

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y necesito recorrer cada valor y saber cuantos caracteres tiene para poder validar que solo me acepte de cada uno de esos valores los que tienen 21 caracteres, y así poder mostrarlo en un session flash. Si pueden ayudarme enserio seria de mucha ayuda. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

puedes filtrarlo por medio de las funciones de colecciones, este tiene una función llamada `filter()`, el cual puede ayudarte para poder determinar si cumple con la condición deseada.

```
$validos = collect($val)->filter(function($valor, $index){
   return strlen($valor) <= 21; // te devolvera los valores que cumplan con la posición y las guardara en la variables $validos
});
```

de esa manera puedes hacer filtrar por el criterio que desees.

Fuentes laravel [filter](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-filter)

Comment: Muchas gracias enserio, yo podría crear una condicional con if con $valor para poder mostrar el session flash?

Comment: puedes retornarlo a un session flash, pero la variable que enviarias seria `$validos`, ya que esta son las que cumple con el filtro que realizastes.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ahora si logro mostrar el session, gracias enserio gracias.